# How to delete all non-numeric rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a dataframe like bellow, where `ID` is numeric value, and `comment1` and `comment2` string that I am importing as a csv. But the data frame is giving result something like this bellow, where `fifth comment` should be in the `comment2` and the original `ID` value is replaced by this. This is happening randomly for only few rows. Moreover, this problem is only occurring when I am importing my **R** code in **Azure ML** studio, in **RStudio** no data misplace is occurring. So what I was thinking, just delete the entire row where the first column `ID` is not a numeric value. As the misplace string value is random long sentence, I can not do string matching to delete the row. And the dataframe is big enough that I just cannot delete the rows manually. Suggestion please.

```
  ID                 Comment1                  comment2
 123             This is first comment        this is second
 234              third comment               fourth comment
fifth comment                                                  
 345               sixth comment              seventh comment
```

You will find a sample of the dataframe here,

```
    df <-
  read.csv(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171YXjzm3FsapXSkqgOSos6UGXNRcd1yxmLyvaRnCX5E/pub?output=csv"
  )
df <- df[-1,]
df <- df[, 1:12]
colnames(df) <-
  c(
    "ID","Created","Comments","Liked_By","Disliked_By", "Recipient_Number",
    "Sender","Recipients","Read_By", "Subject","Introduction","Body"
  )
```

Comment: There are commas in your "comment" fields and you are using commas for the separator in the file.

Comment: I see, now I got the problem. Thanks @cory

Comment: No, I just save as .scv from a xls file, and it shows the column holding text has commas as well.

Comment: Maybe? http://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file#130708

Comment: thanks once again. smiley face. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subset to numeric IDs:

```
subset(df, grepl('^\\d+$', df$ID))
```

The pattern should match values of ID that start and end with digits, and only contain digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your comments description somewhere has (,) in them and it breaks the csv format. To avoid this you can collapse the vectors

Comment: you mean to use `sapply` for the columns where there is probable `,`

Comment: yes...But, I guess I missed the point here. You are trying to read the csv from web. I am not sure if this will work for you. This works when you have a matrix of data and trying to save it in .csv.

Comment: No, this is not working. I do not know, I just save as an xls sheet into csv. I guess that was not a good idea

Comment: deleted the answer, but the reason why you are having that issue is right. It is because csv breaks at (,), so you need to avoid the comma. My solution was to replace the (,) with (&)

Comment: Yes, Now I got it. Thanks for your suggestion really. I guess it is better convert the .xls into .tsv, not .csv. that solves the problem in easy way.

Comment: yeah, tab separated files are much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestion. I just converted a `dataframe, .xls` into `.csv`file where text still included `,` breaks the whole file. **converting into .tsv** is working fine now.